# Using google maps api behind firewall

Tags: google-maps, firewall

I have an application embedding google maps. Works fine. Some users are behind a firewall with very restricted access to the rest of the world.

Does anyone know of a valid list of dns-names/ip-addresses used by the google maps api? I can see what dns-names it loads from in firebug's net panel. But it feels a bit unsafe to use just them. Is there a such list that I can add to the firewalls whitelist?

..fredrik

**EDIT**

I spoke to someone who was working at the maps-team at google. And he said that it's not possible since the ip addresses changes since the maps service is split over a whole range over servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible now. The primary source of information is found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/prelaunch_checklist#firewall

**Configure Firewall to Allow Access to the Google Maps API Services**

**Why it's important:** The Maps API services use a variety of domains, some which do not belong to the *google.com domain. If you are behind a restrictive firewall, it is important you understand which Maps API services use which domains.

Failure to allow access to the correct domains will cause API requests to fail, which can break your applications. For a complete listing of domains used by the Maps APIs, please consult our [portal resource](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal) (login required):

Log in to the [Google Enterprise Support Portal](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal)
The support portal is only available to Google Maps API for Work users.
Navigate to the "Resources" tab
Select the Resource called ["List of domains used by the Google Maps API Family."](https://na4.salesforce.com/a0Z60000000hXGe)
You should allow your applications to access these domains.

Please note that we do not recommend managing firewall restrictions by IP address, as the IPs associated with these domains are not static.

Answer (score 4):

As I see in Chrome's console there are 3 servers that Google Maps are using right now:

- mt0.google.com (ew-in-f100.1e100.net)
- mt1.google.com (ew-in-f102.1e100.net)
- maps.gstatic.com (ew-in-f104.1e100.net)

As you can see all of them are in `1e100.net` domain.

`1e100` equals`1 googol` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the content of the article about domains used in Google Maps APIs. This article is available in Google Cloud support portal:

> This document lists all the domains that are used by the Google Maps Platform when Maps components are loaded. This list of domain is provided to help you set up your firewall configuration, in case your Internet access is filtered by a per-domain policy.
>
> **Important notes**:
>
> - This list is subject to change as new features are rolled out, and may not be up-to-date as new domains are noticed. It is recommended to check this page every 2 months.
> - The entries below containing google.com can be replaced with the other domains where Google Maps has launched: maps.google.co.uk, ditu.google.com, bendi.google.com, ditu.google.cn, bendi.google.cn, mapy.google.pl, etc.
> - Users accessing the API from China will send requests to domains under google.cn and gstatic.cn in addition to google.com and gstatic.com respectively.
>
> **Javascript Maps API (V2 and V3) over HTTP**
>
> The Maps Javascript API V3 (and V2) bootstrap and services (geocoding, driving directions, elevation, kml) use:
>
> - maps.google.com
> - maps.googleapis.com
>
> Static dependencies:
>
> - maps.gstatic.com
>
> Map tiles and traffic tiles:
>
> - maps.googleapis.com
>
> Aerial tiles:
>
> - khmdb0.google.com
> - khmdb0.googleapis.com
> - khmdb1.google.com
> - khmdb1.googleapis.com
>
> Satellite tiles:
>
> - khm.google.com
> - khm.googleapis.com
> - khm0.google.com
> - khm0.googleapis.com
> - khm1.google.com
> - khm1.googleapis.com
> - khms0.google.com
> - khms0.googleapis.com
> - khms1.google.com
> - khms1.googleapis.com
>
> Streetview imagery:
>
> - geo0.ggpht.com
> - geo1.ggpht.com
> - geo2.ggpht.com
> - geo3.ggpht.com
> - lh3.ggpht.com
> - lh4.ggpht.com
> - lh5.ggpht.com
> - lh6.ggpht.com
> - cbk0.google.com
> - cbk0.googleapis.com
> - cbk1.google.com
> - cbk1.googleapis.com
> - cbk2.google.com
> - cbk2.googleapis.com
> - cbk3.google.com
> - cbk3.googleapis.com
> - lh3.googleusercontent.com
> - lh4.googleusercontent.com
> - lh5.googleusercontent.com
> - lh6.googleusercontent.com
>
> Reporting requests:
>
> - gg.google.com
>
> Identification requests:
>
> - id.google.com
>
> **Javascript Maps API (V2 and V3) over HTTPS**
>
> The Maps Javascript API V3 (and V2) bootstrap and services (geocoding, driving directions, elevation, kml) use:
>
> - maps-api-ssl.google.com
> - maps.googleapis.com
>
> Static dependencies:
>
> - maps-api-ssl.google.com
> - maps.gstatic.com
>
> Map tiles and traffic tiles:
>
> - maps.googleapis.com
>
> Aerial tiles:
>
> - khmdb0.google.com
> - khmdb0.googleapis.com
> - khmdb1.google.com
> - khmdb1.googleapis.com
>
> Satellite tiles:
>
> - khm.google.com
> - khm.googleapis.com
> - khm0.google.com
> - khm0.googleapis.com
> - khm1.google.com
> - khm1.googleapis.com
> - khms0.google.com
> - khms0.googleapis.com
> - khms1.google.com
> - khms1.googleapis.com
> - khms2.google.com
> - khms2.googleapis.com
> - khms3.google.com
> - khms3.googleapis.com
>
> Streetview imagery:
>
> - geo0.ggpht.com
> - geo1.ggpht.com
> - geo2.ggpht.com
> - geo3.ggpht.com
> - lh3.ggpht.com
> - lh4.ggpht.com
> - lh5.ggpht.com
> - lh6.ggpht.com
> - cbks0.google.com
> - cbks0.googleapis.com
> - cbks1.google.com
> - cbks1.googleapis.com
> - cbks2.google.com
> - cbks2.googleapis.com
> - cbks3.google.com
> - cbks3.googleapis.com
> - lh3.googleusercontent.com
> - lh4.googleusercontent.com
> - lh5.googleusercontent.com
> - lh6.googleusercontent.com
>
> Reporting requests:
>
> - gg.google.com
>
> Identification requests are not sent.
>
> **Additional domains**
>
> You may also see the javascript v3 API access the following domains:
>
> - googleapis.l.google.com
> - clients.l.google.com
> - maps.l.google.com
> - mt.l.google.com
> - khm.l.google.com
> - csi.gstatic.com
>
> **Maps API Web Services**
>
> The Geocoding API V3 (and V2), the Directions API, the Elevation API, the Distance Matrix API, and the Static Maps API V2 (and V1) use:
>
> Over HTTP:
>
> - maps.google.com (legacy)
> - maps.googleapis.com (recommended)
>
> Over HTTPS:
>
> - maps-api-ssl.google.com (legacy)
> - maps.googleapis.com (recommended)
>
> **Maps Android SDK**
>
> The Maps Android SDK uses these domains over HTTPS:
>
> - clients4.google.com
> - www.google.com
> - csi.gstatic.com

Comment: Can you provide the original link?

Comment: This information was available only for users with Google Maps Premium Plan at https://google.secure.force.com/

Comment: Thank you. I don't have Premium Plan that's why I didn't find this. Do you have any information what are the domain rules in case of 'normal plan'? I cannot find any relevant info about it.