# Google maps for Android, firewall whitelist

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I'm developing a company specific Android application that uses Maps SDK for Android and Google Maps Intents for Android (com.google.android.apps.maps) to show some markers on Google map. Users use directions and streetview Apis on these maps as well. The application will not be published on Google Play as it is completely company specific. Employees will use the app on special company provided devices not on theirs own mobiles. The company provided devices are behind a firewall allowed only to reach some services part of the project.

My question: what firewall rules (domain whitelists) should be configured to reach Maps SDK for Android and Google Maps Intents for Android services?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using google maps api behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800955/using-google-maps-api-behind-firewall)

Comment: No, because I have normal plan (not Premium Plan). Does it mean that domain rules that providing Maps service available only at Premium Plan? I cannot find any relevant documentation about it.

Comment: Domain rules are exactly the same for Premium plan and Standard plan. However, I would suggest reach out to Google Maps support team via your [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) in order to check with them if information I found in Support portal is not outdated.

Comment: I contacted Google Maps support and they confirmed the list of domains are the same in case of Normal Plan.